# Warning RC4011: identifier truncated to

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, resources, visual-studio-2012

I am having trouble compiling RC file. It was absolutely fine in VS 2005 but when I moved to VS 2012 troubles started.

**That is what I have in RC file:**

```
#include <windows.h"  
#include AGPRODVERPATH
```

**That is what I have in .props file:**

```
<ResourceCompile>  
<AdditionalOptions> -DAGPRODVERPATH="\"..\\..\\..\\..\\VisualStudioBuildProducts\\CodeAndFlags\\$(Platform)\\AGDriverControlPanel_$(Configuration)_prodver.h\""
</AdditionalOptions>  
</ResourceCompile>
```

**And that is the error I get:**

- Resources\Win\AGDriverControlPanel.rc(3): warning RC4011:
  identifier truncated to
  'AGDriverControlPanel_Debug_prodverRapifamily.h'
- Resources\Win\AGDriverControlPanel.rc(3): error RC2006: #include
  expected a file name, found '...'
- D:\p4client\ProAudio\dev_vs12\ProAudio\VisualStudioBuildProducts\AGDriverControlPanel\Win32\Debug\RCa59288(62):
  fatal error RC1116: RC terminating after preprocessor errors

Any help?

Comment: `#include expected a file name, found '...' `. I'm just saying, the compiler knows what it's talking about. The first thing that should come to mind is to check your #include lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

<AdditionalOptions> -DAGPRODVERPATH="\"..\..\..\..\VisualStudioBuildProducts\CodeAndFlags\$(Platform)\AGDriverControlPanel_$(Configuration)_prodver.h\""
</AdditionalOptions>

**Is an absolute definition now. Instead there should be:**

<PreprocessorDefinitions>  AGPRODVERPATH="\"..\..\..\..\VisualStudioBuildProducts\CodeAndFlags\$(Platform)\AGDriverControlPanel_$(Configuration)_prodver.h\""
</PreprocessorDefinitions>